# Pl/SQL query a view in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the function below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BUTCE_REPORT_Fun (birim_id IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   retval sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   OPEN retval FOR
      select * 
      from ifsapp.butce_gerceklesme 
      WHERE  budget_year = '2018' 
      AND USER_GROUP = birim_id ;

   RETURN retval;
END BUTCE_REPORT_Fun;
```

and am trying to execute the function this way

```
SELECT * from table(IFSAPP.BUTCE_REPORT_FUN('3008'))
```

the line above generates this exception

> ora-22905 cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

to keep in mind that ifsapp.butce_gerceklesme is a view (which I do not think that it matters).
So how I can solve this. any help is appreciated.
Actually, am trying to create a function that returns rows from the view above according to the parameters provided. so if I can achieve that in another way that would be better.

Comment: @APC it's clear; I need a function that takes a parameter and query a table according to that parameter and returns a table. that is all

Comment: @APC here is the hole query select * from ifsapp.butce_gerceklesme WHERE  budget_year = '2018' AND USER_GROUP = (select con2.CODE_PART_VALUE from IFSAPP.ACCOUNTING_ATTRIBUTE_CON2 con2 where COMPANY = 'XYZ' and ATTRIBUTE = 'ABC' and CODE_PART = 'J' 
         and con2.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE=407 AND rownum = 1 );

Comment: @APC the main table is huge and the inner query assigned to USER_GROUP is selected every time. I need a way to set the inner query as a variable and do the select. in this way, the data is retrieved faster, but I have no idea how to achieve that in pl/SQL

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your question relates to a non-working solution, when really what you should be focused on is solving your **real** problem which is how you might improve the performance of a query..

Comment: Dear @APC; you made my day; I learned a new thing from you today after I read about the XY Problem. I did not know that its described in that way. Anyway, thank you again for your time. regards

Comment: You're welcome. It's good to know that it has a name, because it's a common phenomenon. We've all had moments where we've needed to stop and ask ourselves, "Wait, what is the problem I'm really trying to solve here?" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref Cursors are for use in program calls: they map to JDBC or ODBC ResultSet classes. They can't be used as an input to a table() call. Besides, there is no value in calling your function in SQL because you can simply execute the embedded query in SQL.

> the main table is huge and the inner query assigned to USER_GROUP is selected every time

So maybe what you want is subquery factoring AKA the WITH clause?

```
with ug as (
   select con2.CODE_PART_VALUE 
   from IFSAPP.ACCOUNTING_ATTRIBUTE_CON2 con2 
   where COMPANY = 'XYZ' 
   and ATTRIBUTE = 'ABC' 
   and CODE_PART = 'J'
   and con2.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE=407 
   AND rownum = 1
)
select * 
from ifsapp.butce_gerceklesme t
     join ug on t.USER_GROUP = ug.CODE_PART_VALUE 
WHERE t.budget_year = '2018'
```

Tuning queries on StackOverflow is a mug's game, because there are so many things which might be responsible for sub-optimal performance. But as a rule of thumb you should try to tune the whole query. Encapsulating a part of it in PL/SQL is unlikely to improve response times, and indeed may degrade them.